# How to Fetch the Post in company pages of linked in using Share API/UGC post api with date limitation?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am using linked in share and ugc post api to fetch posts from my organization page. I am unable to fetch the data within the date range.

Is there any options to fetch the data based on date range ?

Is there any query parameter available to append in the GET method.

Example: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?q=authors&authors=List(urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3A1234)&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1575138600000,end:1577817000000),timeGranularityType:DAY)

I have gone through the share statistics page, but it is not helping since it only give the overall share statistics for organization or share specific.